# Синонимизировать [sheets]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте есть две метки на одну тему:

- [sheets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheets) (9 вопросов) *описания нет*
- [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) (586 вопросов) *есть описание*

Синонимизировать их действительно надо, все вопросы по [sheets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheets) действительно про [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet).

Можно конечно и самому всё вырезать, но всё таки предлагаю их синонимизировать, чтобы больше не создавали такую, основная - [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 12 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 9 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'sheets': [sheets] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 589
tag remapping of [google-spreadsheet] and [sheets] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym sheets -> google-spreadsheet was approved!
```

Comment: Ещё надо бы синонимизировать [tag:spreadsheets], он по той же теме.

Comment: @wchistow добавлено

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. А точно надо? Если их синонимизировать, то у нас не будет общей метки для гуглотаблиц, экселя и open office calc'а.

Comment: А зачем такая общая метка?

Comment: Тогда можно сейчас сожалеть что у нас нету общей метки для всех сервисов яндекса!

Comment: На enSO [синонимизнуто](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets/synonyms).

Comment: @чистов_n, ну формулы в них всех примерно одинаковые, поэтому кажется, что вопросы чаще будут одинаково решаться во всех трёх, потому и хочется общую.

Comment: @Qwertiy а какого рода общие вопросы ты ожидаешь, можно пример такого?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну большинство вопросов, связанных с написанием формул, решаются в них одинаково.

Comment: @Qwertiy ты всё ещё говоришь какими-то общими словами без конкретики. Нужен пример вопроса, для которого бы подошёл единый ответ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541358/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/378047/178988 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850345/178988 4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1361263/178988 5. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707581/178988 6. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1467666/178988 7. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812895/178988 8. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/276141/178988 Достаточно примеров?

Comment: @Qwertiy но ведь ты просто привёл вопросы по excel. п.2 вообще не имеет ответа. А остальные, если и подходят к чему-то отличному от MS Excel, то лишь по причине того, что кто-то использует подражание/совместимость с excel. Это не делает ответ обобщённым. Точно так же как можно на [tag:c] дать ответ, который будет работать и для [tag:c++].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, формулы во всём в 90% случаев пишутся одинаково, значит 90% ответов по формулам подходят ко всем таблицам. При чём тут подражание/эффективность? Важно не почему так, а то, что оно именно так.

Comment: @чистов_n Если метка слишком общая, ее точно не нужно синонимизировать с меткой конкретного сервиса. Синонимы только для меток, которые обозначают одно и то же.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight когда (и если) пополнение списка запрещённых меток сделают доступным модераторам, тогда можно будет не использовать синоним. Сейчас же выглядит так, что синоним наиболее подходящее решение.